# How to sort a dictionary into different list or dictionary according to one object value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have 3 class, the class Book that contain a dictionnary of page, in the dictionnary of page we have the class Page and in the class Page you have a dictionary of word that contain the class Word.

the class Word is build like this

```
public class Word : IWord
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public ushort Number { get; set; }
}
```

I need for my projet to sort the Word so that I know if there's to much letter in a word.

I have a function in another file but in the same projet to do this that use a  `int differenceValue`, like this :

```
Optimisation( int differenceValue, string Letter )
{

}
```

I need a list or a dictionnary for every `Word.Letter` that is different and then sort them to know if I can return `false` with my function if the difference between two letter in the alphabet is to big. for exemple we have the word dog, I convert every letter to  is number associate, if my differenceValue is 4 then d = 4; o = 15; g = 7. We sort by order, and we compare the difference between `differenceValue` and `15 - 4`. So it return `false`.

I have no idea where to start, I think I can use LINQ but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a difficult time understanding what you want to do with the dictionaries. I'm thinking you choose dictionaries because it's a way to ensure unique values. So I don't have a complete answer, but the following will return the difference value and the optimization boolean. Maybe that can get you started.

```
bool IsOptimized(int diffValue, string word)
{
    return GetDifferenceValue(word) < diffValue;
}

int GetDifferenceValue(string word)
{   
    if (word == null || word.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        return int.MaxValue;
    }
    
    // use regex to remove non-alpha characters i.e. "check-in" or "one,"
    var wordArray = Regex.Replace(word, @"[^\w.]", string.Empty)
           .ToLower()
           .OrderBy(x => x)
           .Distinct();
           
    return wordArray.Last() - wordArray.First();
}
```